# Enable remote blog publishing for custom blog engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, blogs

I'm writing a very simple lightweight blog engine with ASP.NET MVC 4.  One thing I'd like to allow is remote publishing.  That way I can use something like Windows Live Writer to publish blog posts.  But I'm having trouble finding examples of how I can pull this off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you might take a look at the source code of Mads Kristensen (famous of BlogEngine.net, etc. ) new MiniBlog project.

https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog

It has Windows Live Writer (WLW) support

- Optimized for WLW
- Assumes WLW is the main way to write posts
- You don't have to use WLW (but you should)

The code is based on the `MetaWeblog API`: https://github.com/madskristensen/MiniBlog/blob/master/Website/app_code/handlers/MetaWeblogHandler.cs

Comment: Awesome.  I've just submitted my first test post through WLW.  Just what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: At this point I'm essentially using a stripped down version of MiniBlog.  It's pretty close to what I was looking for.